# Does this series converge? By squeeze theorem.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Positive series $\{x_n\}$  satisfies
$$\ln \frac{{{x}_{n+1}}}{{{x}_{n}}}=\frac{{{x}_{n+1}}-{{x}_{n}}}{{{x}_{n+1}}}+\frac{{{({{x}_{n+1}}-{{x}_{n}})}^{2}}}{2{{a}^{2}}},\;\; n\in\mathbb{N}^*$$ for ${{x}_{n}}\ne x_{n+1},  a>0$. Can we find a constant  $q\in(0,1)$ satisfies $$|{{x}_{n+1}}-a|<q|{{x}_{n}}-a|.$$

Here I can prove  that $a$ is between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$. But I don’t know how to prove it converges. Thank you!

Comment: By "Compression principle" do you mean [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem). Also please add your own thoughts/efforts rather than just copying the question you have.

Comment: No, since constant sequence is obvious a solution to your equation. Also, if the sequence is not a constant, using $1-1/x\leq \ln x$ you can derive $2a^2\leq x_nx_{n+1}$. (Maybe useless)

Comment: To avoid @Oolongmilktea 's objection, one could perhaps divide the equation by $x_{n+1}-x_n$ or $(x_{n+1} - x_n)^2$, or simply add the condition $x_{n+1}\not = x_n$

Comment: One can remove $a$ from the problem immediately by defining $x_n = a y_n$ and $x_{n+1} = a y_{n+1}$.

Comment: let $x_n=ay_n$, we get $$\ln{\dfrac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}}=\dfrac{y_{n+1}-y_n}{y_{n+1}}+\dfrac{(y_{n+1}-y_n)^2}{2}.$$